# Python Tkinter: Loop The Computer's Turn A Certain Amount of Times

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, dice

I'm writing a program for a dice game (Pig). In the game, the player will roll a d6 until they decide to hold their score (passing to the computer) or until they roll a 1, which will automatically make it the computer's turn.

The issue I'm having is that I need the function for the computer's turn to loop ten times. I want the computer to roll the die ten times, where it will either roll a one and pass back to the player or it will hold after ten rolls. How do I get the computer to roll the die ten times without using a loop inside of Tk?

Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.headerFont = ("courier new", "16", "bold")

        self.title("Pig, The Dice Game")
        self.headers()
        self.rollDie()

    def headers(self):
        Label(self, text = "Instructions", font = self.headerFont).grid(columnspan = 4)
        Label(self, text = "Text", font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 1, columnspan = 4)

        Label(self).grid(row = 1, columnspan = 4)
        Label(self, text = "The Game of Pig", font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 2, columnspan = 4)

    def rollDie(self):
        self.btnRoll = Button(self, text = "Roll The Die")
        self.btnRoll["state"] = 'active'
        self.btnRoll.grid(row = 3, columnspan = 4)
        self.btnRoll["command"] = self.playerTurn

        self.btnHold = Button(self, text = "Hold")
        self.btnHold["state"]= 'active'
        self.btnHold.grid(row = 4, columnspan = 4)
        self.btnHold["command"] = self.compTurn

        self.btnPass = Button(self, text = "Pass")
        self.btnPass.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 4)
        self.btnPass["command"] = self.compTurn

        Label(self, text = "You Rolled:").grid(row = 6, column = 0)
        self.lblYouRolled = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblYouRolled.grid(row = 6, column = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = "we")

        Label(self, text = "Options:").grid(row = 7, column = 0)
        self.lblOptions = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblOptions.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = "we")

        Label(self, text = "Player One Turn Score:").grid(row = 8, column = 0)
        self.lblPlayerOneTurnScore = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
        self.lblPlayerOneTurnScore.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = "we")


    def playerTurn(self):
        self.oneTurnTotal = [0]
        self.oneRoll = randint(1,6)
        self.btnHold["state"] = 'active'

        self.lblYouRolled["text"] = self.oneRoll

        if self.oneRoll != 1:
            self.oneTurnTotal.append(self.oneRoll)
            self.lblOptions["text"] = "Roll again, or hold and pass the dice to Player Two."
        else:
            self.lblOptions["text"] = "You rolled a 1! Click 'Pass' to pass your turn to the computer."
            self.oneTurnTotal = [0]
            self.btnRoll["state"] = 'disabled'
            self.btnHold["state"] = 'disabled'


    def calculatePlayerOneTurnScore(self):
        turnScore = sum(self.oneTurnTotal)
        self.lblPlayerOneTurnScore["text"] = turnScore



    def compTurn(self):

        self.compTurnTotal = [0]
        self.compRoll = randint(1,6)

        self.lblYouRolled["text"] = self.compRoll

        if self.compRoll != 1:
            self.compTurnTotal.append(self.compRoll)
            self.lblOptions["text"] = "The computer will roll again."

        else:
            self.lblOptions["text"] = "The computer rolled a 1! Its turn has ended."
            self.compTurnTotal = [0]
            self.btnRoll["state"] = 'active'

    def calculatePlayerTwoTurnScore(self):
        turnScore = sum(self.twoTurnTotal)
        self.lblPlayerTwoTurnScore["text"] = turnScore


def main():
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: What do you mean "without using a loop inside of Tk"?

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop? A short loop that does nothing but a little math is completely harmless.

Comment: are you expecting the computer to roll once, pause a second to let the user know what's going on, roll again, pause, roll, pause? Or, do you want the computer to simulate up to 10 rolls and then return the result?

Comment: Well, I was told that you really shouldn't use a loop inside of Tk because the main function is already a loop. How would I get the computer's function to repeat until it rolls a one or rolls ten times?

Simulating ten rolls and returning the result would be fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a loop inside of Tk.  Actually you can call wait_window() if your dice rolling is in a toplevel window and your mainloop will pause until the rolling is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the dicerolling a toplevel widget and then have your root "wait_window" for the rolling widget to complete.  Create a function inside the toplevel widget that generates the roll and call it ten times

EXAMPLE

```
from Tkinter import *

yourscorevalue=12
cpuscorevalue=10

class dice:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        rollcount=0
        top=self.top=Toplevel(parent)
        while 1:
            roll=self.diceroll()
            rollcount+=1
            if rollcount==10 or roll==1:
                break

    def diceroll(self):
        #Random Dice Roll code

class dicegame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title('Dicerolling Game')
        Label(self.root, text='Your Score').grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='ew')
        Label(self.root, text=yourscorevalue, background='black',foreground='red').grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='ew')
        Label(self.root, text='Computer Score').grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='ew')
        Label(self.root, text=cpuscorevalue, background='black',foreground='red').grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='ew')
        b=Button(self.root, text='Roll The Dice', command=self.roll).grid(column=0,row=2,sticky='ew')
        c=Button(self.root, text="Done", command=self.root.destroy).grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='ew')

        mainloop()

    def roll(self):
        d=dice(self.root)
        self.root.wait_window(d.top)
```